# How to clear chat history in Quickblox?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, chat, quickblox

Quickblox provides a way to delete chat messages(one by one) from the dialog, is there any way to delete all or clear history of the current dialog? And I am not talking about dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete dialog one by one but can't delete all dialog on one click. You need to build your own logic for delete all dialogs. Here, I am able to delete dialog box using below code :

```
// delete currend dialog
function onDialogDelete() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want remove the dialog?')) {
        QB.chat.dialog.delete(currentDialog._id, function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                console.info('Dialog removed');

                $('#'+currentDialog._id).remove();
                delete dialogs[currentDialog._id];

                if(Object.keys(dialogs).length > 0){
                    triggerDialog(dialogs[Object.keys(dialogs)[0]]._id);
                } else {
                    $('#messages-list').empty();
                }
            }
        });

        $("#update_dialog").modal("hide");
        $('#update_dialog .progress').show();
    }
}
```

This feature is already working in cordova sms_chat sample code.

Comment: Thanks , please read my question carefully , i ask about messages not dialogs,right?

Comment: and yes , i can do using looping for each message and delete them,but i don't want to use loop for it.

Comment: If you don't want to use loop, then I don't think that there is any other possible way. Now it's depends on you.